# readthedocs app won't start with apache and django

Tags: python, django, apache

Im trying to get readthedocs to run as an apache application.  I'm following all the instructions, but ive boiled it down to this error in my apache logs.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=2372): Target WSGI script '/opt/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=2372): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils.lru_cache import lru_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 28
     fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
                     ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know enough about this system to know if i should be searching for a server configuration error or if im dealing with a bug in this branch of the app.

ive been following these instructions and since this is going on a dedicated server, im not using a virtualenv

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

my packages folder:

```
alabaster                                  django_filters                        lazr.uri-1.0.3-nspkg.pth         pytz-2013b0.egg-info
alabaster-0.7.6.dist-info                  django_formtools-1.0.dist-info        livereload                       queries
allauth                                    django_gravatar                       livereload-2.4.0.dist-info       README
amqp                                       django_gravatar2-1.0.6.egg-info       markdown                         recommonmark
amqp-1.4.6.dist-info                       django_guardian-1.3.egg-info          Markdown-2.6.2.dist-info         recommonmark-0.1.1.dist-info
anyjson                                    django_haystack-2.1.0.egg-info        mimeparse-0.1.3.egg-info         redis
anyjson-0.3.3.egg-info                     django_kombu-0.9.4.egg-info           mimeparse.py                     redis-2.7.1.egg-info
appconf                                    django_pagination-1.0.7.egg-info      mimeparse.pyc                    requests
babel                                      djangorestframework-3.0.4.dist-info   mkdocs                           requests-2.3.0.dist-info
Babel-2.0.egg-info                         djangosecure                          mkdocs-0.14.0.dist-info          requests_oauthlib
beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.egg-info              django_secure-0.1.2.egg-info          mock-1.0.1.egg-info              requests_oauthlib-0.5.0.dist-info
bs4                                        django_taggit-0.17.1.egg-info         mock.py                          rest_framework
celery                                     django_tastypie-0.12.2.dev0.egg-info  mock.pyc                         slumber
celery-3.1.18.dist-info                    djcelery                              nilsimsa                         slumber-0.6.0.dist-info
celery_haystack                            djcelery_transactions                 nilsimsa-0.3.7.egg-info          snowballstemmer
celery_haystack-0.7.2.egg-info             djkombu                               oauth                            snowballstemmer-1.2.0.egg-info
certifi                                    dns                                   oauth-1.0.1.egg-info             sphinx
certifi-2015.9.6.2.dist-info               dnspython-1.11.0.egg-info             oauthlib                         Sphinx-1.3.1.dist-info
click                                      doc2dash                              oauthlib-1.0.3.egg-info          sphinx_http_domain
click-5.1.dist-info                        doc2dash-1.1.0.egg-info               openid                           sphinx_http_domain-0.2.egg-info
CommonMark                                 docker                                packaging                        sphinx_rtd_theme
CommonMark-0.5.4.egg-info                  docker_py-1.3.1.egg-info              packaging-15.2.dist-info         sphinx_rtd_theme-0.1.8.dist-info
copyright                                  easy-install.pth                      pagination                       stripe
corsheaders                                elasticsearch                         pip                              stripe-1.20.2.egg-info
cssselect                                  elasticsearch-1.5.0.dist-info         pip-7.1.0.dist-info              taggit
cssselect-0.9.1.egg-info                   formtools                             py                               tastypie
ddf_setup                                  guardian                              py-1.4.30.dist-info              test
distutils2                                 haystack                              pyelasticsearch                  testresources
Distutils2-1.0a3.egg-info                  httplib2                              pyelasticsearch-0.7.1.egg-info   testresources-0.2.7.egg-info
django                                     httplib2-0.7.7.egg-info               pygments                         unipath
Django-1.8.3.dist-info                     keyring                               Pygments-2.0.2.dist-info         Unipath-0.2.1.egg-info
django_allauth-0.21.0.egg-info             keyring-5.4.egg-info                  pyquery                          VERSION
django_appconf-1.0.1.dist-info             kombu                                 pyquery-1.2.2.egg-info           virtualenv-13.1.0.dist-info
django_celery-3.1.16.dist-info             kombu-3.0.26.dist-info                _pytest                          virtualenv.py
django_celery_transactions-0.3.2.egg-info  launchpadlib                          pytest-2.7.2.dist-info           virtualenv.pyc
django_copyright-1.0.0.egg-info            launchpadlib-1.10.2.egg-info          pytest_django                    virtualenv_support
django_cors_headers-0.13.egg-info          lazr                                  pytest_django-2.8.0.dist-info    wadllib
django_dynamic_fixture                     lazr.authentication-0.1.3.egg-info    pytest.py                        wadllib-1.3.2.egg-info
django_dynamic_fixture-1.8.5.egg-info      lazr.authentication-0.1.3-nspkg.pth   pytest.pyc                       websocket
django_extensions                          lazr.restfulclient-0.13.1.egg-info    python_mimeparse-0.1.4.egg-info  websocket_client-0.32.0.egg-info
django_extensions-1.3.8.dist-info          lazr.restfulclient-0.13.1-nspkg.pth   python_openid-2.2.5.egg-info     wsgi_intercept
django_filter-0.11.0.egg-info              lazr.uri-1.0.3.egg-info               pytz                             wsgi_intercept-0.10.3.egg-info
```

Comment: Which version of Django you are using?

Comment: Its whatever was installed by pip on the requirements file.  I updated with my packages folder

Answer (score 1):

**This error generally occurs when the Python version with which the `mod_wsgi` is compiled is not compatible with Django version being used.**

It appears you are using Django 1.8. Now, Django 1.8 is compatible with Python 2.7 or above. Apparently, the Python version with which your `mod_wsgi` is compiled is <2.7.

The `mod_wsgi` package is compiled for a specific Python version and linked via a shared library.

From the [`mod_wsgi`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use) docs:

> When `mod_wsgi` is built, the `'mod_wsgi.so'` file should be linked
>   against Python via a shared library. If it isn't and it is linked
>   against a static library, various issues can arise.

**What you need to do?**

You need to check with what Python version, your `mod_wsgi` is compiled with. If your Python version with which `mod_wsgi` is linked is <2.7, you will need to recompile your `mod_wsgi` with Python versions>= 2.7.

**How to check the `mod_wsgi` compiled Python version?**

You can try running the `ldd` command and check the output.

Sample output:

```
$ ldd mod_wsgi.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffeb3fe000)
 libpython2.5.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython2.5.so.1.0 (0x00002adebf94d000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002adebfcba000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00002adebfed6000)
 libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0x00002adec00da000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00002adec02dd000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00002adec0635000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555555554000)
```

Also, here's the [official link](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation) for checking your `mod_wsgi` installation.